# Unable to add more than one model to my collection

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to Backbone, and trying to make a table data using backbone, it has add, edit, delete (CRUD).

In this process I've done the add part, all works fine. But I'm unable to add more than one person using create new list button. Any one assist me to figure out the issue and how to fix this?

Here is the excerpt:

template:

```
<tbody>
    <% _.each(users, function(user){ %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= user.get("firstName") %></td>
        <td><%= user.get("lastName")%></td>
        <td><%= user.get("age") %></td>
        <td><a href="#/edit/<%= user.get("id") %>" class="btn">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    <%})%>
</tbody>
```

// function

```
render:function(){
var template = _.template($("#listTempalate").html(), {users:this.collection.models});
        this.$el.html(template)
},
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YQEf4/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push the data to your array, you're not adding an `id` property.

The "created" data are all sharing the same (non-existant) `id`, and a backbone collection only allows a single instance of the same model (based on the `id`).  So, only the first of the created models is being added to the collection.

What you would do in a real Backbone app is either create a new userModel with the entered data and `.add()` that to the collection, or just call `.add()` on the collection with the raw data.

For your demo, you could just generate an id property before you push the data to the array.